# How to close a panel in GWT in selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium, gwt, selenium-webdriver, panel

There is a panel on top of the window:

```
<div id="kRwPes" class="panel-primary panel panel-noborder panel-modal z-window-shadow" style="position: absolute; width: 30%; top: 28.5px; left: 527.5px; z-index: 1800;>
```

It has a close icon:

```
<span id="kRwPes-close" class="panel-icon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</span>
```

Code :-

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("path to panel-icon/glyphicon glyphicon-remove");
```

I tried using the xpath for this close icon, the classname, but I get an error that the element is not clickable

With GWT, I am not able to use the `.SwitchTo()` function to switch to this popup.

How can I close this panel

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. 
Get all the "close button" elements associated with the page and find the close button that is active and click on it.

```
List<WebElement> g = driver.findElements(By.className("glyphicon"));            
        for (WebElement e: g){
            if (e.isDisplayed()){
                e.click();
            }
        }
```